# NoClassDefFoundError (unknown source) when starting new Activity

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to start an activity

```
`package com.kapzlock.mytestproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle SomeVar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(SomeVar);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.kapzlock.mytestproject.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
`
```

The Manifest xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kapzlock.mytestproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kapzlock.mytestproject.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

It compiles without problems, but when I run the Splash.class, I'm getting an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity` Error. The package name is com.kapzlock.mytestproject and the class that I'm referencing to is MainActivity.class. Has anybody an idea where the mistake could be in?

Comment: Do you import any additional jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following

```
finally
{
   Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(this,MAINACTIVITY.class);
   startActivity(openStartingPoint);
}
```

Remove following from your manifest.xml in mainActivity tag

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.kapzlock.mytestproject.MAINACTIVITY" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it shows an error that the constructor Intent() is undefined.

Comment: The log cat is empty. I'm new into programming, so I don't have a clue.  The console shows this:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source).

Comment: Apparently, it can't find the Class on runtime, but it used to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

This worked for me.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but I'm still having the same error when trying to run it.

Comment: Do you import any additional jar file?

Comment: No I didn't, but since I experienced this error, I changed some settings with the AVD (after reading some tips that I found by searching on google). Since the 'clear' I even experience now that root android classes show a compile error (like Activity and Button). It seems to be an error with the whole setup of my Eclipse and Android SDK.